# Color not set properly to search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm setting up my search bar like so...

```
    self.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Plants"
    searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:255/255, green:127/255, blue:0, alpha:1)
    
    
    if let textField = self.searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UITextField }).first {
        textField.subviews.first?.isHidden = true
        textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
         
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

Now when I run the project in an iPhone 7, it looks properly like so...

[image]

But when I run it in an iPhone XR, it looks like so...

[image]

What could be the reason for this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `searchBar.searchTextField` by default has a slightly opaque background color and so to prevent bleeding of the `tintColor`, we will need to explicitly set the color.

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```